# Why did Thresh become so powerful as a wraith?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the novel *Ruination*, we see the events that led to the formation of the Shadow Isles, Viego's ruination, and the death of Isolde.

Kalista notably takes on her current form upon remembering all those who betrayed her, but she apparently acquired her current level of power over time, as more betrayed souls were added to her "hive mind." Viego is quite powerful from the beginning, but he was already a powerful mage before he became a wraith. Hecarim is not shown to be much more dangerous than the ordinary wraiths at that point.

And then there is Thresh, who is able to manifest his power to take the souls of other wraiths and store them in his lantern almost as soon as he dies and is reconstituted as a wraith. Despite not being a mage in life, Thresh can easily capture the souls of the learned scholars of Helia, who seemed not to become nearly as powerful as he did upon attaining wraithhood.

Why is Thresh so powerful from the outset?